# strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string - error

Tags: php

After months of use my application form suddenly stopped with this error:

```
Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/useraccount/public_html/My_Application.php on line 9
```

line 9 begins the cookie, but even if I remove that it seems to be related to the `strip_tags` line. Why would this suddenly stop working? 
This has worked for months with no issues. The server was `5.3` and I see an upgrade to `5.3.26`. Could that change have actually caused this?

```
if ($_POST)
{
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_start();
    $post = new stdClass; 
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
    $post->{$key} = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
    $post->accident_type =$_POST['accident_type'];
    $_SESSION['post']=$post;
} 
more code continued...
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['key'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's obvious - your `$_POST[$key]` as array and not string. So you need to decide what do do in terms of logic of your application. I can suggest:

```
if(is_scalar($_POST['$key']))
{
   //treat any scalar value as string and do stuff:
   $post->{$key} = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
}
else
{
   //here you need to decide what to do with such things as arrays
}
```

Comment: why would have worked previously for months? that's what I can't figure out. Why would break all of the sudden?

Comment: Because in previous month your `$_POST` did not contain array within it's dimensions. Now you've sent it and got your error.

Comment: What array would I be sending that made it change I guess is the question. I don't recall modifying anything from it's working state. I just want to revert it to it's working state. Thanks for the direction...

Comment: Well, you're accepting your POST data - so array could come even if you've changed nothing in your _application_ at server side. Investigate it on your client side, then.